# How to make Visual Studio resolve path for custom binding

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I have created a new class which inherits from Binding. Visual Studio is not handling the binding as I expected in xaml. This question is specifically related to how Visual Studio interacts with xaml.

I currently have some a `Binding` class implementation:

```
public class CustomBinding : System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
    public CustomBinding() : this(null)
    {
    }

    public CustomBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        //My code here
    }
}
```

When I use my CustomBinding in xaml, I expect to have similar behaviors from Visual Studio.

- `System.Windows.Data.Binding`

  - When I hover over my property, I am shown that text is linked to the PropertyPath.
  - When I click on the property and press F12 (Go to Definition), I am taken to my view model where the property resides.

[image: Binding shows PropertyPath]

- `CustomBinding`

  - When I hover over my property, I am shown that text is of type String.
  - When I click on the property and press F12 (Go to Definition), I am taken to the Object Browser and shown the String class.

[image: CustomBinding shows String]

I've looked at the System.Windows.Data.Binding class using a decompiler in an attempt to see if there were any attributes or other items which would have helped Visual Studio pick up on how to handle these appropriately. I was unable to find any clues which would lend itself to that (which is expected).

My question is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5265281/). However, that question is directly related to Resharper while I am interested in seeing if this is available via Visual Studio 2017.

My inclination is that this is not possible without either implementing my own Xaml Designer for VS. I appreciate any and all insights you might have.